# Plugin nnoremap insert <CR> instead of executing command

Tags: vimscript, command-line, tabbed-user-interface

I am writing a vim plugin that at one point define a buffer only mapping :

```
function! s:DoStuff()
    tabnew

    " ...

    nnoremap <buffer> q :tabclose<CR>
endfunction

call s:DoStuff()
```

Then I call my file for testing with :

```
vim -u plugin.vim
```

But when in my newly created tab and I hit `q` I get :

```
:tabclose<CR>
```

Instead of inserting `tabclose` and actually closing the tab. When I hit `enter` to excute the command I get an error :

[image: A result]
[image]

Do you have an idea ?

I am on OS X with tmux and MacVim 7.4.383.

Thanks,

Comment: Try `$ vim -N -u plugin.vim`.

Comment: What is the output of `:set cpoptions?` when that happens?

Comment: @lcd047 : `cpoptions=aABceFs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I found the solution :

I need to be in `nocompatible` mode to execute the mapping.

So I can add the `set nocompatible` at the first line of my plugin (but I think it's not a good way to do). Or I can start vim with the `-N` flag that set `nocompatible` at vim startup. (thanks @romainl)

Looking at the documentation, I saw that `nnoremap` was not in Vi.

Comment: You need to set `nocompatible` to do just about anything interesting with Vim anyway.

Comment: Or just create a `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: This is why many scripts save the options (`let saved_opts = &cpopts`), restore `cpopts` with `set cpopts&vim`, and reset them at the end (`let &cpopts = saved_opts`)... See [`:help use-cpo-save`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#use-cpo-save)

Comment: Interesting :) but in my case I wasn't using any vimrc, only the plug-in file so the `-N` was more convenient